# PHP euro symbol htmlentities

Tags: php

```
$string = 'ab!:;c+12,.3 €def-x/';
$string = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s€+-]+/', '', $string);
$val=htmlentities($string, ENT_NOQUOTES, );
echo $string,"\n";
```

Echos

```
abc+123 �def-x
```

And not

```
abc+123 €def-x
```

I need to get the Euro symbol through a Regex and into the database but not as the Euro symbol.

Comment: Why specifically the Euro symbol? What's so special about it that you need to handle only it by hand? Smells like a bandaid fix to a bigger encoding problem to me. Also, you're supposedly *removing* the Euro symbol with that regex, it won't go into your database at all.

Comment: nothing specific about it, I want all html characters to be replaced by htmlentities this is a shortened version of the regex.

Comment: Sorry, not getting why you're replacing certain characters with `''` before simply HTML encoding them.

Comment: I just thought it would be better to regex user input as the first step always, I see I could do it differently here but if there is a straight forward solution then why change my order?

Comment: even this is not returning anything (with no regex) $string = 'ab!:;c+12,.3 €def-x/';
//$string = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s€+-]+/u', '', $string);
$string=htmlentities($string, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8');
echo $string."\n";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$string = 'ab!:;c+12,.3 €def-x/';
$string = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s€+-]+/u', '', $string);
$val=htmlentities($string, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8');
echo $string,"\n";
```

Should fix it.

Comment: It echo's nothing on my server

Comment: @user1209203: Are you trying the exact same snippet? What PHP version are you running?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to supply the `u` modifier for the regex, otherwise it doesn't handle Unicode characters:

```
preg_replace('/.../u', ...)
```

If you do so, make sure the source code and text is encoded in UTF-8.